# Insert content in product page

Tags: event-observer, html

I need to insert (via my payment module) html element (div) somewhere (for example under Add to cart button) at product page view.

Should I use event/observer, or maybe there is something other?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

found solution,

https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-button-next-to-add-to-cart-button-in-magento-2/

depends on my needs, injected my own block